# Touchpad on Dell XPS not generating "click" events under Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

Just installed (after a lot of futzing around), now I'm into Linux Mint (Cinammon) for the first time. Something's wrong with my touchpad - I can move it around, and it seems like I can right click, but actually clicking on something, and opening it up using the touchpad isn't working.

I'm on a Dell XPS 13 9360.

So, I see the Firefox icon on the bottom, but can't actually click on it to open it. Same with the command line/terminal icon. Can't open it.

However, the touchscreen seems to be working. I can click on things with the touchscreen, so that's how I can open the command line successfully.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, never mind - I found this article with some details about touchpad problems with Mint:

https://www.technipages.com/linux-mint-configure-laptop-touchpad

This fixed the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).